# R regex extract similar words but one has hyphen

Tags: regex, r, stringr

I have the following data frame:

```
species    size_description
1          "some text Small some text"
2          "some text small-med some text"
3          "some text Med. some text"
4          "some text medium some text"
5          "some text med-large some text"
6          "some text large some text"
```

I would like to write a regex the captures the size in the size description field, so it would look like this:

```
species    size_description                    newSize                            
1          "some text Small some text"         "Small"
2          "some text small-med some text"     "small-med"
3          "some text Med. some text"          "Med."
4          "some text medium some text"        "medium"
5          "some text med-large some text"     "med-large"
6          "some text large some text"         "large"
```

I tried to do it this way:

```
size_regex = paste(
                "[Ss]{1}mall",
                "[Mm]{1}ed\\.*i*u*m*",
                "[Mm]{1}ed\\.*i*u*m*-*\\s*[Ll]{1}arge",       #doesnt work
                "[Ss]{1}mall-*\\s*[Mm]{1}ed\\.*i*u*m*",       #doesnt work
                "[Ll]{1}arge",
                sep = "|"
                )

df$newSize = str_extract(df$size_description, age_regex)
```

BUT, it can't differentiate the ones with hyphens. For example, for species 2 it records it as "small" and not "small-med".

How can I write a regex that will do this in R? I have preference to the stringr package, but anything will do.

Note the reason I leave the option for the full words in my regex is that some descriptions use the full word. For example, some may be "small-medium" while other are just "small-med".

Comment: is size always the third word?

Comment: no, it can be anywhere in the string

Comment: what are the possible `size` elements you are considering?

Comment: I listed them in the newSize field, those are all the possible sizes

Comment: Is **[this](https://regex101.com/r/rR8uU0/1)** good?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this regex will suffice the conditions that you mentioned

```
(\S*(?:[Ss]mall|[Ll]arge|[Mm]edium|Med[.])\S*)
```

**[Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/rR8uU0/2)**

Comment: Yes, that looks good. For my own knowledge can you explain how that regex picks up the hyphen? Say for example if I wanted a separate regex for "small-med" only, how could I do that?

Comment: @OliverOliver actually, what I am trying to do is find the word `Small`, `Large`, `Medium` or `Med.` and picking any word that is just before(_and after_) these mentioned words and are _not spaces_

Comment: @OliverOliver for `small-med`, you can directly use as it is

Comment: Oh, ok I see what you doing. Thanks.

Comment: @OliverOliver glad to help